# Make a copy of a QStandardItem among QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have two different QTreeView called treeViewA and treeViewB. Each one has its own QStandardItemModel: When I click one element of treeViewA I connect the signal with a custom slot. I want to reference the same QStandardItem with all its children in the model of treeViewB, but I become the error *QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x..* Why?
The general idea is two have a tree in the treeViewA which displays only the titles and when the user click one title, show all its properties (children of the title in the QStandardItem hierarchy) in treeViewB so that when the user modifies a property (text() in a QStandardItem) the change is also stored in the modelA.
Thank you really much for your answer!!!

```
MainClass::MainClass(){
    modelA = new QStandardItemModel(); // Class QStandardItem*
    modelB = new QStandardItemModel();

    // Append a subclass of QStandardItem
    modelA->invisibleRootItem()->appendRow((QStandardItem *)item);
    //...


    ui.treeViewA->setModel(modelA);
    ui.treeViewA->setDragEnabled(true);
    ui.treeViewA->show();

    ui.treeViewB->setModel(modelB);
    ui.treeViewB->setDragEnabled(false);
    ui.treeViewB->show();

    QObject::connect(ui.treeViewA, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex&)), this, SLOT(UpdateProperties(const QModelIndex&)));
}



void MainClass::UpdateProperties(const QModelIndex& index){
    QStandardItem* item = planModel->itemFromIndex(index);
    propertiesModel->invisibleRootItem()->appendRow(item); // At this point takes the duplication place although modelB is empty.
}
```

Comment: I think you could set both to use the same model and then apply different filters to the items that you show.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! To be honest I don't have any idea about filters but I will inform me now. A fast solution I have programmed is making a copy of the hole item tree structure up from the clicked item (recursive clone()) and after a change in modelB, I update modelA copying back in the another direction.

Comment: I would second RedX's suggestion. You could set both `QTreeView` instances to the same model. You could imagine that the properties are child objects of the title objects. Thus when selecting the title in the one `QTreeView`, you can use that `QModelIndex` and pass that to the properties `QTreeView` using it's `setRootIndex()` function. You'll only see the child items from that index downwards in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you! I will do it like that.